# ASP.NET MVC RadioButtonFor Not Selected On Load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, radio-button, radiobuttonfor

There are many other questions here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, but I have spent far too much time sifting through them for answers to not finally ask one myself. I have tried many of the solutions found here and none of them work.

My problem is as stated in the title; my radio buttons are not being set on page load and I can't figure out as to why.

In the code below my model has a boolean value CanSubmit, the canSubmitYes and canSubmitNo id's are generated id's using

```
ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("canSubmitYes")
```

and

```
ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("canSubmitNo")
```

My radio buttons and corresponding labels are currently set with the following:

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.CanSubmit, "Yes", New With {.for = canSubmitYes})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.CanSubmit, True, New With {.id = canSubmitYes, .class = "submit-toggle-yes"})

@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.CanSubmit, "No", New With {.for = canSubmitNo})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.CanSubmit, False, New With {.id = canSubmitNo, .class = "submit-toggle-no"})
```

What I have tried:

- Setting the `checked="checked"` properties in the the helpers HTMLAttributes collection
- Strip out all of the HTMLHelper code stuff and simply use basic `<input type="radio" />` controls and for some reason it's STILL not being checked properly on load.
- Tried using a jQuery event to set the 'checked' property of them on load of the document, this too, did not work. (via `.prop("checked", true)`)
- Changed my format of the html helper from `"false"` to `false` to try to force it to understand that the property is a boolean and not a string

There are no other javascript events setting values to these controls. When I observe me clicking the buttons there are no HTML values changed on the objects - which leads me to think that the 'clicked'/'checked' property is a pseudo property or state that the browser holds.

Have I missed something critical or am I way off base here?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I have determined that it has something to do with the local variables I'm using. I now have them in basic `<input>`'s again and if I don't connect them they work as expected. It is only when I try to pair them with a common `name` (the way to tie them together) that they don't work.

```
<input name="radio@(Model.ID)" id="@canSubmitYes" type="radio" class="submit-toggle-yes" @(If(submitterPermission.IsSelected, "checked='checked'", "")) />
<label for="@canSubmitYes">Yes</label>

<input name="radio@(Model.ID)" id="@canSubmitNo" type="radio" class="submit-toggle-no" @(If(submitterPermission.IsSelected, "", "checked='checked'")) />
<label for="@canSubmitNo">No</label>
```

If I remove the `name=''` attribute then it correctly checks the proper element on load. I need these items to be unique as there could potentially be 50+ of such parings on the page.

Comment: here is a DotNetFiddle of what you're trying to do.. https://dotnetfiddle.net/MAqhYq

Comment: Yes, and what you have there is essentially what I'm doing, and yet my radio buttons aren't checked - as yours is in your fiddle.

Comment: might be the way you're defining the `id` parameter.. just use a string value there or leave it off completely and see what happens

Comment: Are you saying neither of the radio buttons is checked? The code you have shown works fine. If the value of `CanSubmit` is `true` the first button will be selected, otherwise the second will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that I had left this question unanswered.

We eventually did not find the problem, but ended up following a different approach. Furthermore I no longer work on that project so I cannot adequately update this question.